# How do I get IE to display CSS DIV tables properly?

Tags: html, css

I get very favorable results in Firefox and Chrome, however, IE just doesn't display the DIV's as tables. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the markup I am using:

CSS

```
.table {
   display: inline-table;
   padding: 3px;
}
.row {
   display: table-row;
}
.cell {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 210px;
   height: 35px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="table">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
      <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your class names are not matching

Comment: What reason do you have for using `div` tags to display a table? That is what `table` is for.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, I have made the classes match.

Comment: I am using div's to display table data since CSS has the table display property. It seems much cleaner to me.

Comment: @KeithGroben When people tell you to use CSS instead of HTML tables in your website they are talking about using something (tables) with a semantic purpose (tablular data) for layout (site structure, other non-tabular data). It is *far* more correct to use tables for tabular data than to try to roll your own system with divs, and you will get the bonus of having something that works well with screen readers, etc.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker I totally see the point. Since it is a display property in CSS I decided to give it a try. It seemed to work on other browsers but not IE. I was wondering how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using div's to display table data—

Hold it *right there*.

HTML has a whole category of markup devoted to tables that has been around since at least HTML 2.0, if not its inception. That's over half a decade before table display properties surfaced in CSS2.1, and just about the same time the first browser wars started.

If it's tabular data, *use a table*!

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is tabular data, I agree that this would be an easy fix. It is just that it works in other browsers but not the most popular one.

Comment: Are you sure using an HTML table doesn't work in IE? It was the first browser to support at least the basic parts.

Comment: @KeithGroben This is not the easy fix -- this is the only fix.

Comment: I agree David. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work in IE8 once you fix the class names. http://jsfiddle.net/Ukg9r/1/